# myModal Javascript Popup not opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an Ebay-Template with several footer links. Normally those links should open in a javascript popup window. Unfortunately the text, which is deposited in the manuel.js File doesn't appear.

Here is the code:

index.html-File:

```
<li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal" data-animation="none">Bestellung</a>
                <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
                    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal_2" data-animation="none">Bezahlung</a>
                <div id="myModal_2" class="reveal-modal">
                    <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

**Manuel.js File:

```
$( "#myModal" ).prepend( '<h1>Retoure / Umtausch</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,etc.</i></p>' );
$( "#myModal_2" ).prepend( '<h1>Link2</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, etc.</p>' );
```

I don't know what's wrong and why the text doesn't appear in the popup! Hope someone could help!

Answer (score 0):

You append the text but you never show the modals so it's normal that they don't show up.

Add `.show()` after the `prepend` and wrap the whole line with the event listener that you want (in this case it seems to be `.on('click', ...)` on the `<a>` tags).